# Meteor throws throwIfSelectorIsNotId exception

Tags: exception, meteor, meteorite

When running some code Meteor throws a throwIfSelectorIsNotId exception. I have two clients running the same code and the exception is thrown when the second client is running the same pice of code.

Cant figure out what this exception means and why it is thrown. Hopefully someone will be able to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For certain operations on the client (since version 0.57 I think it was). When doing an update operation e.g

```
MyCollection.update({name:"John Doe"},{$set:{age:50}});
```

You need to split it into two parts, on the client. (Only on the client).

```
var doc_id = MyCollection.findOne({name:"John Doe"})._id;
MyCollection.update({_id:doc_id,{$set:{age:50}});
```

You need to find the document by the `_id` first then update that document. The selector can only be an `_id` for `update` & `remove` operations.

This is because of a security risk with meteor's design, if there were to be a client side mongodb database it could arbitrarily get information from the server on other operations while determining on whether to allow the update or not. It was introduced in Meteor 0.57.

Comment: Seems this also occurs when trying to perform updates with an $in operator on the client. `MyCollection.update({_id: {$in: idList}}, someModifier, {multi: true})` throws the same error.

Comment: Yes you can't use this type of query on the client. In Essence you have to get the results and loop through and do each one. Multiple Updates aren't supported clientside due to the security issue where you could craft a query to learn about the collection before the update is rejected (Access Denied)