# Add a new field to a document mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am very new to mongodb and have a basic question that I am having trouble with. How do I get the ID field of a document that has already been created? I need the ID so i can update/add a new field to the document.

```
//newProfile is an object, one string it holds is called school
if(Schools.find({name: newProfile.school}).fetch().length != 1){
    var school = {
        name: newProfile.school
    }
    Meteor.call('newSchool', school);

    //Method 1 (doesn't work)
    var schoolDoc = Schools.findOne({name: newProfile.school});
    Schools.update({_id: schoolDoc._id}, {$set: {enrolledStudents: Meteor.user()}});

    //Method 2?
    //Schools.update(_id: <what goes here?>, {$push: {enrolledStudents: Meteor.user()}});
}
else {
    //Schools.update... <add users to an existing school>
}
```

I create a new school document if the listed school does not already exist. Schools need to hold an array/list of students (this is where i am having trouble). How do I add students to a NEW field (called enrolledStudents)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do, there is no need to get the `_id`. When you use `update`, just switch out the `{_id: schoolDoc._id}` with your query. Looks like using `{name: newProfile.school}` will work, assuming that the rest of your code does what you want it to do.

While that would work with the normal Mongo driver, I see that Meteor does not allow your update query to be anything but `_id`: [Meteor throws throwIfSelectorIsNotId exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687453/meteor-throws-throwifselectorisnotid-exeption)

First, make sure that you're pulling the right document, and you can try something like this:

```
var school_id = Schools.findOne({name: newProfile.school})._id;
Schools.update({_id: school_id}, { $push: { enrolledStudents: Meteor.user()}});
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to do a little debugging to see what in particular about it isn't working.

Comment: When i do this i get an error in the web console "throwIfSelectorIsNotId"

Comment: Are you using the regular Node Mongo driver, Mongoose, or something else?

Comment: You're using the meteor mongo driver. Meteor does not allow client side updates unless by _id.

Comment: The `throwIfSelectorIsNotId` error is because there is a typo in EmptyArsenal's answer.  Add '{' and '}' around the `_id: school_id` part.

Comment: It's true that there were missing curly braces, but the error was related to an earlier query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do. Here's my analysis and understanding so far with a couple pointers thrown in:

```
if(Schools.find({name: newProfile.school}).fetch().length != 1){
```

this would be more efficient

`if(Schools.find({name: new Profile.school}).count() != 1) {`

`Meteor.call('newSchool', school);`

Not sure what you're doing here, unless you this will run asynchronously, meaning by the time the rest of this block of code has executed, chances are this `Meteor.call()` function has not completed on the server side.

```
//Method 1 (doesn't work)
var schoolDoc = Schools.findOne({name: newProfile.school});
Schools.update({_id: schoolDoc._id}, {$set: {enrolledStudents: Meteor.user()}});
```

Judging by the if statement at the top of your code, there is more than one school with this name in the database. So I'm unsure if the `schoolDoc` variable is the record you're after.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your help. To clarify... Meteor.call('newSchool', school) is calling a Meteor method called newSchool which creates a new document in the Schools collection.  the first 'if' statement checks to see if that school exists in the Schools collection, if not create it using the current users school.  The second part (where i am having trouble) is once that school is created how do i go about adding the first user AND any other users that want to join later?  I am trying to use Schools.update({...}) to add the initial student and future students to the correct school document.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having trouble because of the asynchronous nature of Meteor.call on the client.

Try doing something like this:

```
// include on both server and client
Meteor.methods({
  newSchool: function (school) {
    var newSchoolId,
        currentUser = Meteor.user();
    if (!currentUser) throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Access denied');

    // add some check here using the Meteor check/match function to ensure 'school'
    // contains proper data

    try {
      school.enrolledStudents = [currentUser._id];
      newSchoolId = Schools.insert(school);
      return newSchoolId;
    } catch (ex) {
      // handle appropriately
    }
  }
});


// on client
var schoolExists = false;

if (Schools.findOne({name: newProfile.school})) {
  schoolExists = true;
}

if (schoolExists) {
  var school = {
        name: newProfile.school
      };
  Meteor.call('newSchool', school, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      alert('An error occurred...');
    } else {
      // result is now the _id of the newly inserted record
    }
  })
} else {

}
```

Including the method on both the client and the server allows Meteor to do latency compensation and 'simulate' the insert immediately on the client without waiting for the server round-trip.  But you could also just keep the method on the server-side.

You should do the enrolledStudents part on the server to prevent malicious users from messing with your data.  Also, you probably don't want to actually be storing the entire user object in the enrolledStudents array, just the user _id.